# Correct preposition in this context

Tags: prepositions

There is a hill very close to a house, but the house is not touching the hill. We can say that **the hill is starting a few metres away from the house.**

Which is correct to say in this situation:

> My house is situated **by** the hill.
>
> My house is situated **under** the hill.
>
> My house is situated **down** the hill.

....or something else?

Please explain.

Comment: There are several applicable answers. The hill starts a few meters away from the  house. Which one would you choose?

Answer (score 1):

While all the examples that you give are correct, and you could use any of them. "By" is simple and descriptive. "Under" could be odd, unless the house is a tunnel. "Down" would be describing the position of the house relative to someone at the top of the hill.

There are other alternatives that you could use:

You can say the house is **at the bottom/foot** of the hill.